# jQuery animation: Time Delay Trouble

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I affectively use the jQuery animate() with complete: ...etc.  Each loop can be set at any speed and it's essentially toggling the display.

```
If () { 
      //do this
} else {
      //do that
}
```

After running "do that" the "do this" will run perfectly again **SO LONG AS I WAIT** for the equivalent of the timing of the loop; essentially, if each loop is set to run in 1500ms then a 1-2 sec delay after the "do that" executes will enable the "do this" to work fine.

If I don't wait I get some divs displaying their textual content even though the code has it set not to do that, although the 1500ms animation portion of the loop still performs nicely.  I've tried implementing some .clearQueue() functions on both the end of the "do that" and the beginning of the "do this" loop to no avail.

Is there a function that will essentially "clear" what is obviously clearing by way of "waiting" for the 1-2 seconds to pass?

I cannot post the code.

BTW: I was running an easing function ("easeInOutQuad") which worked great in FF but Chrome and Epiphany browsers got stuck on it.  The problem above persists when using either linear or swing default easing functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the animate method a function as a callback...

```
$('.stuff').fadeOut('slow', function() {
  $('.stuff').fadeIn('slow');
}};
```

This will wait until the fade out completes before preforming the fade in.